# json post to an API using curl in php

Tags: php, json, rest, api, curl

i have this question, i try to send a request to one API, this APPI expect an application/json so i first test in postman to see the results and works as i expected, but in my code no, next my code, 
 public function myfunctiion()

{
       $req = '{
        "myparams": myvalues,
        "myparams": myvalues,
        "myparams": myvalues,
        "myparams": {
            "myparams": myvalues,
            "myparams": "myvalues",
            "myparams": "myvalues",
            "myparams": myvalues
        }';
    $jsonRequest = json_decode($req, TRUE); ;

```
    try{
        self::setWsdl('API url');

        $context =[

            'Content-Type: application/json', 
            'Accept: application/json',

        ];

        self::setContext($context);
        self::setRequest($jsonRequest);

        return  InstanceCurlClient::curlClientInit();



    } catch(\Exception $error){
        return $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and y let my curl config

```
public static function curlClientInit(){
        try{
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            self::getWsdl());
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,    true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     self::getContext());
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     self::getRequest());
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            return $response;

         }catch(\Exception $error) {
            if (empty($response)) { 
                throw new SoapFault('CURL error: '.curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch)); 
            } 
        }
        curl_close($ch);        
    }
```

so my result if i test this return to me a 0 and i expect this error
{
    "error": "Credenciales no válidas"
}
and if past an  asociative array instance a json and i use json_enconde so return false and i dont now why cause if do the same in postman i give the error cuse i expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to use json_encode instead of putting in an array for the CURL_POSTFIELDS if you are accessing a JSON api.

The built-in json_encode function often fails to encode a data, if you did not set the proper $options flag for the data. This is quite annoying actually.

When it returns false, you can call `json_last_error_msg()` to learn the reason why it cannot encode your data. That would hopefully let us dig more into the problem.

Comment: thanks mate i saw it was ok the response cause is a status code 403 so its ok